# Web server autonomous actions?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have site hosted by a web server, that is basically made by PHP+Javascript and MySQL.

I'd like to find the way to let the web server execute asynchronous and autonomous actions like run some calculation on database data or some AI algorithm. For the moment, I'm avoiding cron jobs with PHP because they are blocking and therefore affecting web users experience.

Which could be the best ways to implement it (including solutions that are not compliant with the present solution)?

Comment: cron tasks, queued jobs?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver runs under linux you could use the cron:

in a terminal window:

**# crontab -e**

and add:

***/10 * * * * wget http://localhost/do_some_calculations.php**

to run your script every 10 minutes.

Comment: If the scrpt executed in such PHP page is "long", it can be blocking and therefore affecting web users experience. Am I right?

Comment: Yes indeed, also by executing pages from the cron you don't need a user surfing a webbrowser to do some calculations. For example, if you want to generate reports and email them daily to some users then it's better not to depend on some visitor.

However, if you have "long" pages but these calculations are ment for the user who is visiting the site you could load this content with ajax and make a visible progressbar.